# Equation inside table won't make a line break

Tags: tables, equations, amsmath

I have been stuck on how to make amsmath in an equation environment make a line break. I have tried multiple methods such as multline, etc. but to no avail.

Here's my code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\small
\centering
\caption{Afkast- og risikomodeller}
\label{CAPMFFAPT}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|l|@{}}
\toprule
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Navn\end{tabular}} &\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Opfattelse og måling af \\ systematisk risiko\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Egenkapitalens\\ risikopræmie \\ (ERP) - model\end{tabular}}} \\ \midrule   
\textbf{CAPM}                                                                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Systematisk risiko enkapsuleres i én faktor, der \\ måler et enkeltaktivs afkastsensitivitet mod den \\ teoretiske markedsportefølje. Risikoen måles \\ som beta, \(\beta\), som er hældningskoefficienten der \\ opnås ved at regressere enkeltaktivets afkast \\ mod afkastet for markedsporteføljen.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                    & \(r_i=r_F+\beta_i*(\bar{R}_M-r_F)\)                                                                                                                \\ \midrule
\textbf{Fama-French}                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Systematisk risiko enkapsuleres i tre faktorer, \\ der alle tager afsæt i det enkelte aktivs sensitivitet \\ over for følgende faktorer: 1) markedsporteføljen \\ (se CAPM) 2) SML: en portefølje konstrueret ud \\ fra virksomhedsstørrelser'1 3) HML: en portefølje \\ konstrueret ud fra book-to-market ratios. Risikoen \\ måles derfor som tre faktorer, \(\beta_1\), \(\beta_2\), \(\beta_3\) som er \\ hældningskoefficienten der opnås ved de tre \\ regressioner.\end{tabular} &


\(\bar{R}_i=r_F+\beta_{i}*(\bar{R}_{M}-r_f)+\beta_{SML}*(\bar{R}_{SML})+\beta_{HML}*(\bar{R}_{HML}\))

\\ \midrule
\textbf{APT}                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Systematisk risiko enkapsuleres i adskillige B, som \\ estimeres på baggrund af individuelle risiko faktorer \\ - ligesom i Fama-French. APT kan anskues som en \\ generaliseret model af Fama-French, hvori \\ analytikerens eget antal af faktorer og definition \\ heraf anvendes. Risikoen måles derfor som x antal \\ faktorer, \(\beta\), der opnås ved x antal regressioner.\end{tabular}                                                                          & \(r_E=r_F+ \sum_{n=1}^{j=k}\beta_j*(RP_j\))                                                                                                                \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

It looks like this, when I compile the file: [image]

I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining `\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|l|@{}}` define it as `\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|p{.4\textwidth}|@{}}` that is the last column as a parbox with a specific length  so that the equation breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\small
\centering
\caption{Afkast- og risikomodeller}
\label{CAPMFFAPT}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|p{.4\textwidth}|@{}} %%change as required
\toprule
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Navn\end{tabular}} &\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Opfattelse og måling af \\ systematisk risiko\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Egenkapitalens\\ risikopræmie \\ (ERP) - model\end{tabular}}} \\ \midrule   
\textbf{CAPM}                                                                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} Systematisk risiko enkapsuleres i én faktor, der \\ måler et enkeltaktivs afkastsensitivitet mod den \\ teoretiske markedsportefølje. Risikoen måles \\ som beta, \(\beta\), som er hældningskoefficienten der \\ opnås ved at regressere enkeltaktivets afkast \\ mod afkastet for markedsporteføljen.\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                                    & \(r_i=r_F+\beta_i*(\bar{R}_M-r_F)\)                                                                                                                \\ \midrule
\textbf{Fama-French}                                                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Systematisk risiko enkapsuleres i tre faktorer, \\ der alle tager afsæt i det enkelte aktivs sensitivitet \\ over for følgende faktorer: 1) markedsporteføljen \\ (se CAPM) 2) SML: en portefølje konstrueret ud \\ fra virksomhedsstørrelser'1 3) HML: en portefølje \\ konstrueret ud fra book-to-market ratios. Risikoen \\ måles derfor som tre faktorer, \(\beta_1\), \(\beta_2\), \(\beta_3\) som er \\ hældningskoefficienten der opnås ved de tre \\ regressioner.\end{tabular} &


\(\bar{R}_i=r_F+\beta_{i}*(\bar{R}_{M}-r_f)+\beta_{SML}*(\bar{R}_{SML})+\beta_{HML}*(\bar{R}_{HML}\))

\\ \midrule
\textbf{APT}                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Systematisk risiko enkapsuleres i adskillige B, som \\ estimeres på baggrund af individuelle risiko faktorer \\ - ligesom i Fama-French. APT kan anskues som en \\ generaliseret model af Fama-French, hvori \\ analytikerens eget antal af faktorer og definition \\ heraf anvendes. Risikoen måles derfor som x antal \\ faktorer, \(\beta\), der opnås ved x antal regressioner.\end{tabular}                                                                          & \(r_E=r_F+ \sum_{n=1}^{j=k}\beta_j*(RP_j\))                                                                                                                \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on `tabularx`, with no white strips at the top of coloured cells. I replaced `\bar` with a more appropriate `\widebar` borrowed from `mathabx`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, caption, makecell}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{ >{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}\small\centering
\caption{Afkast- og risikomodeller}
\label{CAPMFFAPT}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}|l|X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|@{}} %%change as required p{.3\textwidth}
\toprule
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}
\textbf{Navn} & \thead{Opfattelse og måling af \\ systematisk risiko} & \thead{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\thead{Egenkapitalens\\ risikopræmie \\ (ERP) - model}} \\ \midrule
\textbf{CAPM} & Systematisk risiko enkapsuleres i én faktor, der måler et enkeltaktivs afkastsensitivitet mod den teoretiske markedsportefølje. Risikoen måles som beta, \(\beta\), som er hældningskoefficienten der opnås ved at regressere enkeltaktivets afkast mod afkastet for markedsporteføljen. & \(r_i=r_F+\beta_i*(\widebar{R}_M-r_F)\) \\ %
\midrule
\textbf{Fama-French} & Systematisk risiko enkapsuleres i tre faktorer, der alle tager afsæt i det enkelte aktivs sensitivitet over for følgende faktorer: 1) markedsporteføljen (se CAPM) 2) SML: en portefølje konstrueret ud fra virksomhedsstørrelser'1 3) HML: en portefølje konstrueret ud fra book-to-market ratios. Risikoen måles derfor som tre faktorer, \(\beta_1\), \(\beta_2\), \(\beta_3\) som er hældningskoefficienten der opnås ved de tre regressioner &
\(\begin{multlined}\widebar{R}_i=r_F +\beta_{i}*(\widebar{R}_{M}-r_f)\\ +\beta_{SML}*(\widebar{R}_{SML})+\beta_{HML}*(\widebar{R}_{HML}
)\end{multlined}\)
\\ \midrule
\textbf{APT} & Systematisk risiko enkapsuleres i adskillige B, som estimeres på baggrund af individuelle risiko faktorer- ligesom i Fama-French. APT kan anskues som en generaliseret model af Fama-French, hvori analytikerens eget antal af faktorer og definition heraf anvendes. Risikoen måles derfor som x antal faktorer, \(\beta\), der opnås ved x antal regressioner.%
 & \(r_E=r_F+ \sum_{n=1}^{j=k}\beta_j*(RP_j\)) \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `tabularx`-based solution, which deliberately seeks to create an "open" look, e.g., by omitting all vertical rules and all interior horizontal rules. It uses an `enumerate` environment to structure the material in one of the cells, it replaces a couple of instances of text-mode `x` with math-mode `\times`, and it uses a `multlined` environment for the formula that involves a line break. I've omitted the `*` (multiplication) symbols -- if you really must, use `\cdot`, not `*` -- and I've fixed what I consider to be a typo (`r_f` to `r_F`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools,enumitem}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage[danish]{babel} % is this correct?

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\small
\caption{Afkast- og risikomodeller}
\label{CAPMFFAPT}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lYY @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Navn} 
& \textbf{Opfattelse og måling af systematisk risiko}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
& \textbf{Egenkapitalens risikopræmie (ERP) - model} \\ 
\midrule   
\textbf{CAPM}                                                                
& Systematisk risiko enkapsuleres i én faktor, der  måler et enkeltaktivs afkastsensitivitet mod den  teoretiske markedsportefølje. Risikoen måles som beta, \(\beta\), som er hældningskoefficienten der opnås ved at regressere enkeltaktivets afkast mod afkastet for markedsporteføljen. 
& \(r_i=r_F+\beta_i(\bar{R}_M-r_F)\)                                                                                                                  
\\ 
\addlinespace
\textbf{Fama-French}                                                        
& Systematisk risiko enkapsuleres i tre faktorer, der alle tager afsæt i det enkelte aktivs sensitivitet over for følgende faktorer:
\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
\item markedsporteføljen (se~CAPM) 
\item SML: en portefølje konstrueret ud fra virksomhedsstørrelser'1 
\item HML: en portefølje konstrueret ud fra book-to-market ratios. Risikoen måles derfor som tre faktorer, \(\beta_1\), \(\beta_2\), \(\beta_3\) som er hældningskoefficienten der opnås ved de tre regressioner. 
\end{enumerate} 
&\( \begin{multlined}[t]
\bar{R}_i=r_F+\beta_{i}(\bar{R}_{M}-r_F)\\
+\beta_{\textrm{SML}}(\bar{R}_{\textrm{SML}})
+\beta_{\textrm{HML}}(\bar{R}_{\textrm{HML}})
\end{multlined} \)
\\ 
%\addlinespace
\textbf{APT}                                                                 
& Systematisk risiko enkapsuleres i adskillige B, som  estimeres på baggrund af individuelle risiko faktorer  - ligesom i Fama-French. APT kan anskues som en  generaliseret model af Fama-French, hvori analytikerens eget antal af faktorer og definition heraf anvendes. Risikoen måles derfor som $\times$ antal faktorer, \(\beta\), der opnås ved $\times$ antal regressioner. 
& \(r_E=r_F+ \sum_{j=1}^{k}\beta_j(\mathit{RP}_j\)) 
\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```